# Handling key pressed in QLineEdit which instance is in QMainWindow

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

My goal is to send message to server while I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Below I post solution that works everytime when key is pressed and doesn't matter which key it is. How can I get key that is acctualy pressed?

```
from sys import argv, exit

from interface import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeyEvent
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from client import connect_to_server, send_message


class Communicator(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_message_box_textChanged(self):
        server_socket = connect_to_server()
        message = self.ui.message_box.toPlainText()
        send_message(message, server_socket)


def main():
    main_application = QApplication(argv)
    window = Communicator()
    window.show()
    exit(main_application.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using [auto-connection](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#connecting-slots-by-name), you can simply change the name of your slot to this:

```
    def on_message_box_returnPressed(self):
        ...
```

This uses the [returnPressed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#returnPressed) signal, but a slightly better choice might be to use the [editingFinished](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) signal:

```
    def on_message_box_editingFinished(self):
        ...
```

Using *explicit* signal connections, your code would look like this:

```
class Communicator(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.message_box.editingFinished.connect(self.sendMessage)

    def sendMessage(self):
        server_socket = connect_to_server()
        message = self.ui.message_box.toPlainText()
        send_message(message, server_socket)
```

Comment: As I see I made mistake in title, in fact the type of message_box is QPlainTextEdit which does not have returnPressed or editingFinished signals. Your explicit solution is correct as well as auto-connection one so I mark your answer as a right answer for question. It would be nice if you could provide solution for QPlainTextEdit.

Comment: @Janusz. The `QPlainTextEdit` is a **multi-line** editor, so it makes things much more complicated to use the enter key to send the message. Are you sure you want to do things this way? Why not just have a button that sends the message? You could also add a keyboard shortcut to the button, and this could all be done very easily in Qt Designer. Or if you really don't want the button, you could add just the keyboard shortcut, which wouldn't require much code.